# CKAsset (NSData) to UIWebView to share with ActivityViewController

Tags: ios, swift, xcode8, uiactivityviewcontroller

I have PDF Files as CKAssets, which are called and presented in a UIWebView without issue. I have managed to manipulate the code so as the CKAsset will present in a ActivityViewController, but this is within the func method and I wish to assign this part to an Action button. My question is how can I call a few lines within a function? or have sufficient references outside the func to make the action button work?

Here is the func code -

```
func queryRecord() {

    let container = CKContainer.default()
    let publicDatabase = container.publicCloudDatabase
    let predicate = NSPredicate(format: "recordID = %@", CKRecordID(recordName : documentID))
    let query = CKQuery(recordType: "Documents", predicate: predicate)

    publicDatabase.perform(query, inZoneWith: nil, completionHandler: ({results, error in

        if (error != nil) {
            DispatchQueue.main.async() {
                self.notifyUser("Cloud Access Error", message: error!.localizedDescription)
            }

        } else {
            if results!.count > 0 {

                let record = results![0]
                print(record)

                DispatchQueue.main.async() {

                let docTitle = record.object(forKey: "documentName") as! String

                    self.title = "\(docTitle)"

                    let docType = record.object(forKey: "documentType") as! String

                    if  docType == "PDF" || docType == "pdf" {


                    if let asset1 = record.object(forKey: "documentFile") as? CKAsset {
                        let doc1Data : NSData? = NSData(contentsOf:asset1.fileURL)
                        self.docWebView.load(doc1Data! as Data, mimeType: "application/pdf", textEncodingName: "UTF-8", baseURL: NSURL() as URL)
                        let filenameURL = [(asset1.fileURL)]

                        let activityController = UIActivityViewController(activityItems: filenameURL, applicationActivities: nil)
                        self.present(activityController, animated: true, completion: nil)

                        }

                    } else {
```

I have tried to reference filenameURL outside the code, but it does not recognise that filenameURL is no member of the class.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out (I think). Here goes -

I changed

```
let filenameURL = [(asset1.fileURL)]
```

to

```
self.filenameURL = [(asset1.fileURL)]
```

then added

```
var filenameURL : Any?
```

to the ViewController Class. Which allowed me to add the relevant code to the actionButton -

```
@IBAction func activityVCButton(_ sender: UIBarButtonItem) {
        let activityController = UIActivityViewController(activityItems: (filenameURL as? [Any])!, applicationActivities: nil)
        self.present(activityController, animated: true, completion: nil)
         }
```

I think the key, which I seemed to be missing was the Any?, but I am happy to be corrected if there was something more fundamental I was missing.